# Can I use "exchange" instead of "discourse"? What exactly is "media discourse"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, vocabulary, phrase-choice, formal-language

Please explain me like I'm 5 what is *discourse* in context of media. I understand it as the *message* sides of a debate exchange through there attitude towards the problem but then I don't understand what is meant by *media discourse*. Is it the bare exchange of words among politicians/activists? Or does it refer to the discussions in media about a given topic?

Could I use *exchange* or *discourse* in a sentence like this: ***"The debate in media has very sharpened recently."***?

Comment: **discourse** is academic register for the media palaver as  subject of analysis--its context, rhetorical strategies, etc.

Comment: **has very sharpened** is not idiomatic; the adverb is not used in that way, sandwiched inside a present perfect verb construction.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo What can I use insted of "has very sharpened"? Thanks!

Comment: **The media debate has sharpened** is often used. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22debate%20has%20sharpened%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en  Sometimes it is used transitively, sometimes intransitively.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you! So is it right to use "media discourse" as the "rhetorical strategies" of some newspaper? Such as _They lead an agressive discourse_?

Comment: I understand that it's supposed to be an _academic register_ but I'm struggling to understand the phrase even in my own language and how it's used in the common news language.

Comment: **Discourse** can mean something as simple as "discussion", and you can refer to an ongoing discussion between two people as their discourse, and you can refer to debate in the media over a particular issue as "the media discourse on such-and-such".   But as I said, **discourse** has become an academic buzz-word, so be aware of that, and use the term advisedly.